# Last minute Alhambra tickets in Granada

Tags: tickets, spain, architecture, andalusia

I have heard that tickets to visit the Alhambra get sold out months in advance. Isn't there an option to get last-minute tickets? (Legally, for sure)

If anyone has any information it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several suggestions to choose from:

1. Buy the Alhambra card which includes a ticket to enter the Alhambra on the day.
2. Book a guided tour, there are almost always tickets online.
3. Get up early, if you want to wait in the line get there early as some tickets are sold on the day
4. Visit the free parts of the place that can be entered without a ticket

More suggestions/details can be viewed in [this guide](https://tourscanner.co/blog/alhambra-tickets/).

Comment: Maybe a service like `viator` has tickets for entry and guided tours (on short notice) available.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks guys for the answer. I think ill do the option 3. :) Getting up early is not an issue.